# How to keep the header of the file when filtering using awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file that looks like this with a header. I am just showing the first 8 columns although there are 26 columns.

```
id  Id  Study   Site    CancerType  Sex Country unexpected_duplicates
468768  1032    Response    Karlburg    VN  Breast  Female  Germany 
468769  1405    Response    Santiago        Prostate  Male  Spain
```

I want to filter the Cancer type (column 5) by "Breast" using this command which works fine:

```
awk '($5 == "Breast")' PCA.covar > PCA.covar1
```

The only problem is my header is not printed and the first line is missing  in the output.

So I modified my command to:

```
awk 'NR==1; NR > 1 ($5 == "Breast")' PCA.covar > PCA.covar1
```

And I see that while the header is there, it has not filtered by Breast:

```
id  Id  Study   Site    CancerType  Sex Country unexpected_duplicates
468768  1032    Response    Karlburg    VN  Breast  Female  Germany 
468769  1405    Response    Santiago        Prostate  Male  Spain  
68772  RQ56001-9 Response   Maastricht      Prostate  Male  Netherlands
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: what is the input field delimiter? if the answer is 'white space' then `Breast` shows up in column/field #6 (`awk/$6`), and the 'Prostate' lines appear to have one less column/field which means we need some means of distinguishing which columns may be missing and/or which columns contain embedded white space

Comment: I have just realised, I am fixing this problem. Some words should be together but there is a space between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:
`awk 'NR==1 || $5 == "Breast"{print}' PCA.covar > PCA.covar1`

Comment: What does NR==1 mean? Does it mean keep header/first line?

Comment: NR==1 means `if this is the first record`.  The above program translates to: `if this is the 1st record or if the 5th field is "Breast", then print the record.`